# Permission denied. Error code: 3 Error message from server: Permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am logging into my amazon aws production box using WinSCP and i have successfully setup Tomcat 6. But in webapps folder when i transfer some webservice i get error as:

Permission denied.
Error code: 3
Error message from server: Permission denied

Please help me out to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what instance type you are using, but it sounds like you are on some flavor of Linux. You need to `chmod` or `chown` the webapps directory so you can place files there, or you can place them elsewhere (like your home directory), then log in and use `sudo mv` to move it in place.